# System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission when accessing folder outside web site location

Tags: asp.net

Environment: Windows 2008 R2 x64 [IIS7.5]

From my asp.net application, I am trying to access a folder that is not under web application folder itself. It is something like DirectoryInfo("D:\MySecretFolder")
I get thrown the following error.

> 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed

Application pool is using NetworkService account as its identity and I have given that account full rights on that folder. Is there anything else I am missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access any files through the system's IIS, you have to give the IIS user accounts access to the file as well, not just the app pool. I am not certain if these are the same accounts for all versions of IIS, but I know IIS 7 uses these accounts:

IUSR
and
IIS_IUSRS

This is, of course, assuming you are running it around in IIS.

Comment: I took it to next level and gave "Everyone" full control on that folder and still no go.

Comment: Let me ask you this. When you are targeting the file, are you targeting it by drive letter on the server, like it is in your example?

Comment: It is being accessed exactly as my example, by drive letter. I have even tried to debug using ProcessMonitor to see what user account is having issue, I do not see any entry in there as well.

Comment: Its just an example :-) The actual code reads this path from a configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing physical file outside the directory is just as accessing any other file from any other application. The key thing is to understand who are You when You try to gain access. If You are using the IIS (which I think is the case) the Your app is running in an App Pool. App Pool is identified to the system by a specific user account. You can check it using the IIS console (probably default user who is a member of IIS_WPG).

When You try to access a directory that is outside the WebApp the worker process of IIS running in contect of a particular user must be able to access the desired file/dir. You can either give user the permission to access this particualr permision (via filesystem for example), IMPERSONATE a user that has a permission to access this to this resource for this particular demand (via impersonation api and Principal related classess).

One more thing to read is Code access security. I do not know If You use it, or even aware of it, but it's good to know the facilities that the framework provides

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd984947.aspx

Comment: Thanks for providing some comments luckyblue. I am very familiar with CAS and pool identities. I think "Everyone" group covers everything. I am having issues with that group as well. I have a feeling that I am missing some basic IIS configuration itself or some security policy in server itself that is preventing the access.

Comment: Add a demand permission (or attribute) from CAS to check whether it will work? If not try impersonating a know user (or even an account) that has access to this resource. Obtain a Thread.CurrentPrincipal to look who are YOu impersonated as and check his permissions

Comment: This is account that shows up as windows principal NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE and has FULL access on the folder. Checking on explcit DEMAND on CAS now. I am not sure if pool using .Net 2.0 framework on Windows 2008 is actually using new CAS stuff from ASP.Net 4.0

Comment: It turned out that at some point I had changed trust level of the application to "medium" which caused all IO's to fail outside virtual folder. Changing it to "Full" fixed the issue. Now I am looking at creating a custom medium policy to not open up the application too much.